# Postfix MySQL percentage error in query

Tags: mysql, email, postfix

I have a somewhat complex SQL query that I'm using to get alias forwarding e-mail in `Postfix`. The problem is that `Postfix` uses `%s` as it's insert of alias mark in the SQL query. I think this causes the query to fail for Postfix while it works when inserting it directly to `MySQL` (replacing the `%s` with a test alias)

```
SELECT email FROM members JOIN groups ON mgroup_others LIKE CONCAT('%,', g_id, ',%') OR member_group_id = g_id WHERE g_title LIKE CONCAT('%[', '%s', ']%');
```

The `Postfix` error:

```
postfix/smtpd[9585]: fatal: db_common_parse: /etc/postfix/mysql-aliases.cf: Invalid query template: SELECT email FROM members JOIN groups ON mgroup_others LIKE CONCAT('%,', g_id, ',%') OR member_group_id = g_id WHERE g_title LIKE CONCAT('%[', '%s', ']%');
```

Are my guess at the error right and/or how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you need to add double `%%` so that Postfix parses it to `%` when executing the query.

Reference: http://www.postfix.org/mysql_table.5.html